# Removed read and execute permissions from the root directory

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-14.04, chmod, ubuntu-server

I typed this:

```
sudo chmod o-rwx "$CACHE/"
```

The directory was on a windows harddrive and was literally named "$CACHE". $CACHE is not a variable, and I realize now that the double quote doesn't escape the '$' sign. So what really happened was this:

```
sudo chmod o-rwx /
```

I did this over SSH and was immediately unable to do anything on the server. I got `permission denied` errors for everything; ls, chmod, sudo, etc. Once I disconnected, I was unable to reconnect.

So I dragged the server to a monitor and keyboard and selected recovery mode in grub. I opened up a root terminal and am now able to at least interface with the computer. However, all the file permissions appear fine. However, when I try to fix the issue using `chmod o+rx /`, I receive a `Read-Only file system` error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly linux is not my strong suit. Apparently I just made it so no one but `root` could list or read files.

The fix was to boot and select recovery mode from grub. Type the following to remount my partition as `rw`

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and then just do the opposite of what I did to break it

```
chmod o+rx /
```

All fixed!